# Play back to back audio in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have to play two audio files back to back.
I have a generic file which says:
"My name is"

then follows another audio file which has another audio string.

For example: say a.mp3 has "My name is"
                 b.mp3 has "John"

But when I set contentURL of MPMoviePlayerController. It skips the first audio and plays the second audio.

Here is my code:

```
- (void) playPromptAudio
{[appDelegate.globalPlayer setContentURL:[NSURL 
             URLWithString:@"http://localhost/a.mp3"]];

    [appDelegate.globalPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [appDelegate.globalPlayer play];

    while (appDelegate.globalPlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying ) {
        // dirty hack, do gracefully
        // do nothing
    }

    [appDelegate.globalPlayer setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/b.mp3"]];
        [appDelegate.globalPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [appDelegate.globalPlayer play];
}
```

But when I run the code, only "John" is played.

After debugging the code, I see that the audio starts playing after executing the entire function so it is obvious that "John" is played since it is set last. But is there a way to prevent this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link for MPMoviePlayerController play back

Below code Play MpMoviePlayer with nodification:

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
        self.moviePlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]
                    autorelease];
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
        moviePlayer.view.frame = view_video.bounds;
        moviePlayer.scalingMode= MPMovieScalingModeFill;
        moviePlayer.controlStyle =MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
        [moviePlayer Play];
```

below function is called MpMovieplayerController Playbackfinished:

```
     -(void)doneButtonClick:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlayer is finished..!");
     }
```

Thanks....!